# lightuserdata and pointers to const

Tags: c, lua

Say I have a C function that returns a pointer to const and I want to expose this function to lua. How do I do that? I cannot use `lua_pushlightuserdata` to push the return value of that function onto the stack because `lua_pushlightuserdata` expects an argument of type `void *`, not `void const *`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use light userdata, you have no other option then to cast it to a `void*`.

The other option is to use full userdata. That adds complexity but also gives you more control and the ability the check the type.